# How to make bootstrap nav collapsing from specific resolution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently my bootstrap nav is collapsing into button when the browser width is 768px and less ... how can i change it 800px and less ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a custom build of bootstrap.

You need change the `@screen-sm` variable in the "media queries breakpoints" section on [this](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) page.

1. Change the `@screen-sm` variable to `800 px`
2. Then scroll to the bottom and click the `Compile and Download` button.
3. Take the downloaded files and replace the other bootstrap files you have.

***Note: this will also change the breaking point for all of your `col-sm-xx` classes too but that should not be a big deal.***